Issue with Azure SSO Login: AuthenticationFailureException in Umbraco CMS
I have a .net Umbraco CMS project that was handed over to me to see if I can add login via Azure SSO. I found the package Umbraco.Community.AzureSSO and configured the Azure settings provided to me. Initially, when logging in, it redirected in a loop to the login page. After making several changes, when I try to log in, I get the following error:
Copy code

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler\`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

My appsettings is configured as the documentation states (changing the values to the real ones):
"AzureSSO": {
    "Credentials": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Domain": "<domain>",
      "TenantId": "<tenantId>",
      "ClientId": "<clientId>",
      "CallbackPath": "/umbraco-microsoft-signin/",
      "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/umbraco-microsoft-signout/",
      "ClientSecret": "<clientSecret>"
    },
    "DisplayName": "Azure AD",
    "DenyLocalLogin": true,
    "AutoRedirectLoginToExternalProvider": true,
    "TokenCacheType": "InMemory",
    "GroupBindings": {
      "<AD group>": "<umbraco group>",
      "<another AD group>": "<umbraco group>"
    },
    "SetGroupsOnLogin": true,
    "DefaultGroups": [
        "editor"
    ],
    "Icon": "fa fa-lock",
    "ButtonStyle": "btn-microsoft",
    "LogUnmappedRolesAsWarning": false
},

And my Startup class looks like this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Community.DataProtection.Composing;

namespace proyect
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _env = webHostEnvironment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webHostEnvironment));
            _config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(_config.GetSection("AzureSSO:Credentials"));

            services.AddUmbraco(_env, _config)
                   .AddBackOffice()
                   .AddWebsite()
                   .AddDeliveryApi()
                   .AddComposers()
                   .Build();

            services.AddCors();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            if (!env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseCors(options =>
                    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:44304")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            }

            app.UseUmbraco()
                .WithMiddleware(u =>
                {
                    u.UseBackOffice();
                    u.UseWebsite();
                })
                .WithEndpoints(u =>
                {
                    u.UseInstallerEndpoints();
                    u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
                    u.UseWebsiteEndpoints();
                });
        }
    }

    public class Composer : IComposer
    {
        public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.AddUmbracoDataProtection(); // Adds Umbraco data protection configuration
        }
    }
}


What is Umbraco Version and .NET Core Version?

"Umbraco.Cms" Version="13.0.3" y net8.0

Are you sure you have looked over the app registration in Azure portal as well as the enterprise apps sections (you can configure both and they have unique variables that might be worth revising. They can be found in the Azure portal App Registrations and Enterprise Apps, respectively.  with the correct information, especially concerning the scope, permissions and app roles? Make sure too go to the Api permissions and grant the correct  ones to your app, such as "offline_access", which is crucial for some sign-ins.
Microsoft graph API permissions can be used under the API permissions under App Registrations (your app name). I usually just look at those APIs and write my app roles/scopes/api permissions from the ones that are listed there by mixing and matching a few words around.
It does look like the fatal  error is derived from misconfiguration in the token configuration, and since you are using openidconnect be sure you have all the small details specific to this protocol. It relies on your configuration of the Token exchange and the correct permissions and scopes. I hope this answer can give some clue in this mysterious affair.
I want to edit this answer with this link:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2
The samples they provide are always worth looking at for illuminating bits and fragments that are easily overlooked.
